# How to change programmatically cell values of bound DataGridView without receiving exceptions?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have problems trying to change programmatically the content of a cell of a bound DataGridView.

I implemented a minimal piece of code to show the problem.

Do the following steps to replicate the problem:

- Launch example
- Write the title content to create a new row
- CTRL+C on inserted title
- Move to grid's empty row to force the creation of a new row
- CTRL+V on title cell
- Click on previous row (new row creation is cancelled)
- Click again to the empty row to force the creation of a new row
- Exception: **Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.**

Here it is the code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _dgv As New DataGridView
    Private _Movies As New System.ComponentModel.BindingList(Of Movie)

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        Me.Controls.Add(_dgv)

        _dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        _dgv.DataSource = _Movies

        AddHandler _dgv.KeyDown, AddressOf DataGridView_KeyDown

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)

        If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
            _dgv.CurrentCell.Value = Clipboard.GetText
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Class Movie
        Public Property Title As String
    End Class

End Class
```

For sure there is something wrong in my implementation but I spent many hours searching a workaround without success. Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: What is the DataGridView bound to?

Comment: @Casey It is bound to BindingList(Of Movie), all written in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the form in the constructor, make sure the EditMode of the DataGridView is DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter.  This makes the cell we are pasting to enter edit mode as soon as it receives focus and makes the new row stick instead of being cancelled if we move away from it.

```
 Public Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    Me.Controls.Add(_dgv)

    _dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    _dgv.DataSource = _Movies

    AddHandler _dgv.KeyDown, AddressOf DataGridView_KeyDown

    _dgv.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
End Sub
```

Then, instead of setting the cell value, set the Title property of the underlying Movie:

```
Private Sub DataGridView_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
        Dim Mov As Movie = _Movies.Last
        Mov.Title = Clipboard.GetText
        _dgv.Refresh()
    End If

End Sub
```

When you add a new row in the DataGridView, the BindingList is automagically adding a new Movie object to the list.  _Movies.Last should gets you the newly added Movie.

Comment: It works for already created rows, but how can I make CTRL+V works also in a new row? I would like that a new row is created when I paste the value in the last row cell but, at the moment, the cell content is filled but when I click on any previous grid rows, the last row creation is canceled and content lost.

Comment: @Drake I was going to mention that, but I thought that was the behavior you wanted.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @Drake I think I have it, check my updated answer and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice trick, maybe I could use it, but in reality this small example I made hides a bigger problem I am facing. Practically I need a way to change a value programmatically when adding a new row avoiding the exception mentioned in the question ("Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.")

Comment: @Drake You still get an exception with the solution I posted?  I guess I'm a little confused what the problem would be with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the DataGridView event  UserAddedRow?

[system.windows.forms.datagridview.useraddedrow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.useraddedrow%28VS.90%29.aspx)